# Is there any way to bring an ASP.NET MVC application into "single user mode", rejecting new logins?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a strategy/approach that can be built to bring an ASP.NET MVC application into "single user mode" gracefully? By "single user mode" I mean something that when activated will block all new user access/logins, but allow existing users to complete their sessions and log out.

SCENARIO:  I need to republish an active MVC application during the day in order to patch errors. Since we are conducting a new release I need to be able to do these patches sometimes a few times a day to squash bugs. Our users are all over the world and I don't have the ability to contact them individually to tell them of the patch, especially if it is a quick fix that is needed. So far I've just been republishing which means for some users their sessions will be destroyed, they will get errors when trying to navigate from one screen or form to another, etc.

What I would like is a feature that will let me log in as the site admin (custom Identity auth), flip a switch, and from that point forward (unless I flip the switch again) no new logins will be accepted. I would also need the ability to monitor sessions and ideally mark individual sessions for termination immediately if necessary, which I'm not sure is possible out of the box at all.

If there is no NuGet package or at least some code sample out there that can do it I'm considering rolling my own. One approach is giving the app admin a screen to set a boolean Application variable that is then checked during each user's login. If that Application variable is true then the authentication logic redirects the user to a friendly message that logins are disabled. Session management would be trickier, maybe have the base controller update an Application variable (dictionary?) on each page load, and then the admin can view a screen that shows a list of those sessions and can flag them for termination? And then the next time a flagged user loads a screen the base controller logs them out since they were flagged for termination. But I'm not sure if there will be threading/deadlock/etc issues with everyone accessing this Application variable repeatedly like that.

For reference, the application is used by about 3-5K different users per day, about 25-30k screen/page views per day. Backend is a combination of Oracle and SQL Server but that shouldn't matter, unless it would be better to track the session info in the DB.

This is not a hard requirement, but the impact on the users when the site goes down can be severe, so I want to make it as graceful as possible. Right now it is crude.

Comment: Hi Dave, Have you found solution?

Comment: @LukaszMakowej No sorry I haven't, but then I haven't had much time available to dive into it. If I do I'll try to remember to come back and update this question with an answer though. And ping you. :)

Comment: No  worries, Thanks.